# Extract data from osm.pbf with GDAL

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr, water

I tried osmosis, osm2pgsql, osmfilter, and probably most of OSM related tools in order to extract polygon rivers and water bodies.

Among the tools, OGR is intuitive and returns good results so far

Based on the OSM TagInfo, I am supposed to use the tags below to have river/water polygons

```
water=*, waterway=*
```

Here are the results of water=* from multipolygon below
[image]

It maybe look legit, though I do not see wide rivers (the basemap is OSM).

And I extracted `waterway=riverbank` from linestrings and it only gives me a partial riverbanks from Openstreetmap.

[image]

So, just to check what I've missed using query conditions, I extracted all the linestrings and checked the missing river areas.

[image]

It does not have any data as you may see.

I was just curious how come OSM has polygon shape of riverbanks/river polygons? if there are no information in raw data?
Or, is it OGR's failure?

And, are there any ways that I can have water areas from openstreetmap raw data?

Answer (score 1):

Well,, I ended up using imposm3 and it gave me what I wanted to have.

It works great with linux without installing but with MacOSx you have to do some trick to install.